# How to use EventEmitter inside Meteor?

Tags: events, meteor, eventemitter

Sorry for my english. I tried to use EventEmitter inside Meteor + React, but when I emit an event - nothing happen. When I console.log main Event object, it seems like all ok. Are there any instructions or example about it? Thanks.